# How to check if a textbox is enabled or not

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a asp Textbox control, which is disabled via javascript. How do I check using C# whether the textbox is enabled/disabled ?

Comment: please share more information like your code

Comment: You can't, really. The client-side state of the control is not part of the control from ASP's point of view.

Comment: You can't check it

Comment: When executing any javascript in your code all the server-side-code was executed long before. Thus you can´t access the *curent* browser-state from ASP. You´d have to send a new request towards your server.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I wanted to check the textbox state after a button click , such as submit button

Comment: Then why not simply also send the textbox´ state as hiden field as well?

Comment: @HimBromBeere WIll txtbxName.Enabled not work?

Comment: Try it out, but I guess no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you´re doing on JavaScript happens on the client-side of your code (e.g. a Browser), not on the server-side where your ASP-file resides. This is why the server has no clue on what you´re doing via any client-side script.

As others allready mentioned the server just sens HTML that in your case also contains some Javascript-code. However it is plain text. So in the moment you send that HTML back to the client the server is done and expects new requests.

So the only thing you can do is to *send a new request* containing the textbox´ enabled-state via a hidden field on your form. So whenever you send a request to your server you also send the fields value also.

Answer (score 0):

Textbox on HTML is not directly available on server side.
Its usually input of type='text' which is part of a FORM on the html.
When the form get submitted and input name (your textbox) is sent to the server and there you get your value.

The server just sends HTML , if there is some javascript logic on the client that disables the textbox (set it to readonly i assume) you need to use the same logic on the server and reach the conclusion if the textbox is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have disabled your textbox at client side using js, you can't check it at server end. The asp textbox is rendered in html as input type=text. It is no longer an asp server control. So the only way is through js again.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers **Do not submit** the disabled inputs.

Check this [link](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#disabled) :

> .. the INPUT element is disabled. Therefore, it cannot
>   receive user input nor will its value be submitted with the form.

if you have a form like this for example :

```
<form method="POST" action ="Home/login">
     <input type="text" id="inputUserName" name="inputUserName">
     <input type="password" id="inputPassword" disabled name="inputPassword">
     <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

On your server Side you will receive inputUserName **but you will not receive** inputPassword because it is disabled